# sqllite db android not adding user properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting a "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"

```
public class userDB  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfo";

// Assignment table name
private static final String TABLE_USERINFO = "user";

// Assignment Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";

Context context;
public userDB (Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERINFO + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TOKEN + " TEXT" +  ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERINFO);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding user
public void addUser(authToken user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TOKEN, user.getToken());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USERINFO, null, values);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Inserted" + values.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}



// Getting All Users
public List<authToken> getAllUsers() {
    List<authToken> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERINFO;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            authToken user = new authToken();
            user.setToken(cursor.getString(1));

            // Adding user to list
            userList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return user list
    return userList;
}

// Update User
public int updateUser(authToken user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TOKEN, user.getToken());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_USERINFO, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getUser().getId())});
}

// Delete user
public void deleteUser(authToken user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USERINFO, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getToken()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting User Count
public int getUserCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERINFO;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

I am reading the info in like this: (and userinfo.getToken) is spitting out the token, its something with the sql not adding in db properly.

```
                           userDB db = new userDB(getApplicationContext());
                            dbs = db.getWritableDatabase();
                            //db.onUpgrade(dbs, 1, 1);
                            // Inserting Contacts
                            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .." +                

                             userInfo.getToken());
                            db.addUser(new authToken(userInfo.getToken()));


                            // Reading all 
                            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                            List<authToken> contacts = db.getAllUsers();

                            for (authToken cn : contacts) {
                                String log = "Token: " + cn.getToken();
                                // Writing Contacts to log
                                Log.d("Name: ", log);

                            }
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: so that error was fixed by Nikole91 below. My current issue is that I am facing an issue when I am trying to log the token it shows as null, itll say Name: null, but the toast is coming back with the token, what does that mean?

Comment: Please post the definition of the class authToken.

Also, in the method getAllUsers(), try 

> SELECT id, token from...

 instead of

> SELECT * from...

 to make sure that cursor.getString(1) will give you the value of token.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you setting context? I think the problem is with the toast message.
You should set context in your constructor method:

```
Context context;
public userDB (Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: ok, great. That worked! But I am facing an issue when I am trying to log the token it shows as null, itll say Name: null, but the toast is coming back with the  token, what does that mean?

Comment: First, try removing your db.close() in addUser() and check if that solves it. If not, try using insertOrThrow() instead of insert() in addUser() to verify if the row is indeed being inserted. It will throw an exception if the row can't be added. If it is indeed saving the data, check your getAllUsers() method.

Comment: Try that and let me know if an exception is being thrown, we'll work from there. But first try removing the db.close() :)

Comment: I tried and tested. The thing is it is inserting, but it is inserting as null.. Even on the toast in add user on values.toString shows the token, but in the db it is coming as null.. which is weird. The token looks like this "11~sBptM6DhDBuN6p6ow6GckHbCGuAVttSqG1k2NeCxhCGs9jJj89sFKYnxLXjr4am5" could there be anything wrong with the way I am inserting the text of this?

Comment: Oh... maybe is that ~ symbol, let me do a quick test

Comment: Try inserting any other text without special characters.

Comment: Did you tried to log the cursor data from getAllUsers for all indexes? Just to make sure the correct index is 1

Comment: I fixed it. Issue was the add user.

Comment: Nice! Can you post what was the problem/solution? :)

Comment: The issue was that the class was not in the same package as the activity I was calling

Answer (score 0):

This may not be related but in the method getUserCount(), cursor.getCount() should be called before cursor.close().